# A question on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $M$ be an invertible $4 \times 4$ real matrix, and let $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Consider the matrix
$$\displaystyle \mathcal{M} = \mathcal{M}(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = [\mathbf{u} | M \mathbf{u} | \mathbf{v} | M \mathbf{v} ].$$
Here the notation is that the columns of $\mathcal{M}$ are $\mathbf{u} , M \mathbf{u} , \mathbf{v} , M \mathbf{v}$ respectively.

For generic $M$ and for generic pairs $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$, $\mathcal{M}$ will be invertible and so the only vector orthogonal to all four columns will be the zero vector. If $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are proportional then $\mathcal{M}$ will have rank at most two, and there is no way of determining a unique direction which is orthogonal to all of the columns. However, there exist pairs $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ has rank three, and hence $\ker \mathcal{M}^T$ is 1-dimensional and there should be an algebraic formula which gives a generator in terms of $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ and $M$. Our $M$ will always be chosen so that generically $\mathcal{M}$ is invertible and there exist $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ has rank three.

The motivation here is a generalization of the cross-product in $\mathbb{R}^3$. There the goal is to find an algebraic expression which gives the generator of the kernel of $[\mathbf{u} | \mathbf{v}]^T$,  namely the cross product $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$.

One way to do this is to note that the condition that $\ker \mathcal{M}^T$ is non-trivial is equivalent to the condition that $\det(\mathcal{M}) = 0$. Expanding, we find that

$$\displaystyle \det(\mathcal{M}) = Q_M(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})$$

which is a bi-quadratic form in $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$. Fixing $\mathbf{u}$, we then obtain a quadratic form $\mathcal{Q}_{M, \mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{v})$ in $\mathbf{v}$, which has an obvious solution $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}$. Using the general theory of quadratic forms one can then parametrize all solutions to the equation $\mathcal{Q}_{M, \mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{v}) = 0$. From here one can then find the kernel by taking a Laplace expansion, just like in the 3-dimensional case with the cross product.

Is there a more "linear" method of describing the set, and perhaps in a way which is more symmetric in $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$?

Comment: Since you have already fixed $M$, "Generically, $\mathcal M$ will be invertible" seems to mean "generically in $(\mathbf u, \mathbf v)$", but that can be false, so I guess it means "generically in $(M, \mathbf u, \mathbf v)$".  Similarly, read literally, "there exist pairs $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf v$ such that $\mathcal M$ has rank three" can be false; so probably it should be "there exists $(M, \mathbf u, \mathbf v)$ such that …".  Because of these concerns, I am confused about what set is "the set" that you are describing linearly.  Is it a set of triples or of pairs?

Comment: @LSpice Your concerns are valid, and in my case of interest the $M$ will be "generic" in the sense that both conditions on $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ do occur generically. I will modify the question to include this assumption

Comment: OK, thanks.  So you have fixed such an $M$, and are seeking to describe the set of all $(\mathbf u, \mathbf v)$?

Answer (score 1):

If ker ${\cal M}^{T} $ is one-dimensional, there are two possibilities:

Case 1: $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},M\mathbf{u})$ are linearly dependent; then $M\mathbf{v} $ is linearly independent of the other three, and we can construct the vector $\mathbf{w} $ orthogonal to all four vectors via $\mathbf{w}_{i} = \epsilon_{ijkl} \mathbf{u}_{j} \mathbf{v}_{k} (M\mathbf{v} )_{l} $.

Case 2: $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},M\mathbf{u})$ are linearly independent; then $M\mathbf{v} $ is linearly dependent on the other three, and we can construct the vector $\mathbf{w} $ orthogonal to all four vectors via $\mathbf{w}_{i} = \epsilon_{ijkl} \mathbf{u}_{j} \mathbf{v}_{k} (M\mathbf{u} )_{l} $, and we can also add arbitrary multiples of $\epsilon_{ijkl} \mathbf{u}_{j} \mathbf{v}_{k} (M\mathbf{v} )_{l} $, as long as the result doesn't cancel.

We can furthermore consolidate the two cases into the expression
$$
\mathbf{w}_{i} = \epsilon_{ijkl} \mathbf{u}_{j} \mathbf{v}_{k} [(M\mathbf{u} )_{l} + (M\mathbf{v} )_{l}
+\mbox{sgn}(\epsilon_{mnop} \mathbf{u}_{n} \mathbf{v}_{o} (M\mathbf{u} )_{p} \epsilon_{mqrs} \mathbf{u}_{q} \mathbf{v}_{r} (M\mathbf{v} )_{s})(M\mathbf{v} )_{l}]
$$
because in either case, it reduces to the form specific to that case already given. Here, the last term in the square brackets is a kludge to take into account the loophole pointed out by Willie Wong in comments, that the $M\mathbf{u} $ and $M\mathbf{v} $ components orthogonal to both $\mathbf{u} $ and $\mathbf{v} $ may cancel; this last term eliminates such a cancellation. Maybe one can make this less ugly and completely symmetric in $\mathbf{u} $, $\mathbf{v} $ again.

Comment: What does $\epsilon_{i j k l}$ mean?

Comment: $\epsilon_{ijkl} $ is the totally antisymmetric (Levi-Civita) tensor. Sorry, I'm more fluent in this notation than in producing the appropriate combination of wedges.

Comment: I am not sure about your final equality. Can it not be the case that $M(u+v)$ is in the span of $u$ and $v$?

Comment: For example, set $M = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1\\ -1 & 1 \\ & & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & & 1\end{pmatrix}$. If you set $u = (1,0,0,0)$ and $v = (0,1,0,0)$, then each of $Mu$ and $Mv$ is linearly independent of $u$ and $v$. And $\{ u,v, Mu, Mv\}$ is linearly dependent. But $Mu + Mv = 2u$ and so your $w$ as constructed is $0$.

Comment: Probably you meant that the kernel of $\mathcal{M}^T$ is the linear span of $\{\epsilon(u,v,Mu), \epsilon(u,v,Mv)\}\}$?

Comment: @WillieWong - Ah, you are right, I hadn't considered that loophole. I've fixed it with an unfortunately somewhat ugly kludge that constructs a linear combination of $M\mathbf{u} $ and $M\mathbf{v} $ which does not lie in the span of $\mathbf{u} $, $\mathbf{v} $.

Comment: Incidentally: any linear combination of the four 3-vectors $ u\wedge v\wedge Mu, u\wedge v\wedge Mv, u\wedge Mu\wedge Mv, v\wedge Mu\wedge Mv$ will necessarily vanish under the action $(u,v)\mapsto (\rho u,\rho v)$ with $\rho\in SO(2)$ some rotation in the plane of $u\wedge v$. This is because $-I\in SO(2)$ and each of the four 3 vectors swap signs under negation of $u$ and $v$, and hence by the intermediate value theorem (the space of 3-vectors is one dimensional) for some $\rho$ you hit zero. Hence a "simple multilinear construction" is not possible.

Comment: This is not an issue for the cross product as $u\wedge v$ is preserved under $SO(2)$ rotations, it also having an even number of factors.

Comment: @WillieWong - Yes, that explains nicely why we have to do what we have to do. Thank you!